# android application not closing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, exit

I am in trouble, I want to start my application from starting every time but it's not being.

1. When I exit from my application & come again. I found same activity which I have left before exit.
2. Now If I **shut down or switch off** my Android Device direct when my application is in foreground & then I **switch on device again**. I get same activity which I have left earlier. But I want to fresh application from login page. Because my setter & getter is null after switch on device, and I found all value null in my application.

My Manifest file is below:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".screens.ScreenSplash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".screens.LoginActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".screens.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".screens.MainMenu"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

Kindly help me which is the problem & what should I do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to close the current activity when ever your application goes to background. Is this your requirement?

Comment: any update on this question?

Answer (score 2):

Add to your activity manifest

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

Comment: i add this in my .Main activity & I switch off my device but still same issue.

Comment: Because of your declaration android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden", when the device is switch off, you will get onConfigurationChange save your activity members there.

Comment: Why do do want to handle configuration changes yourself.

Comment: i have add this for orientation handling .

Comment: Your main activity is portrait only, why don't you declare the whole app portrait? Else, you have to register for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and call finish when receive this broadcast.

Comment: requirement in both orientation. ok i try broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

According to your Manifest .Main is the launcher activity. so when your application is launched from icon tap then this is the first activity to display and rather if your application is not having any other activity on top of the stack.

so if you want to see the fresh login activity then make the login activity as launcher activity.

Comment: we can make both activity as Launcher Activity? If I make Login as launcher then Its will first but Main have some services which should start every time.

Comment: launcher activity is always one. what you can do is from main activity you can start the login activity after few seconds

Comment: main issue i have not found . But through Broadcast i close app completely then every time launch main activity

Comment: ok..but what you can do is in every activity override onStop and finish the particular activity there. so your stack will be empty

Comment: no no just give the action on broadcast & when my device will shutdown or off launch only one activity & put finish();
&android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try setting `launchMode` to `standard`?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html